# Batched rendering with Uniform Buffer Object

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm changing my basic renderer to make it a batched renderer to improve performance.
I've successfully changed my vertex data to draw all my meshes in a single batch, but when I want to handle multiple materials a problem arises.

Obviously I can't use normal `uniforms` since I'm batching a lot of meshes, so I thought about using Uniform Buffer Object to store all the materials data.

The problem is, how can I update this buffer?

If I setup my UBO like this:

```
layout(std140) uniform MATERIAL
{
    vec4 Color[20];
    float Specular[20];
    float Roughness[20];
    float Metallic[20];
    float ReflectionIntensity[20];
};
```

I don't think that then, when I submit the data of the single material, I can use a starting offset calculated based on the material index and submit the data like this:

```
struct Material {
    float color[4];
    float specular;
    float roughness;
    float metallic;
    float reflectionIntensity;
};

int bufferStride = 32; // 16 (vec4) + 4 (float) + 4 (float) + 4 (float) + 4 (float)
int offset = bufferStride * updatingMaterialIndex;

Material m;
m.color...

glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, offset, &m, sizeof(Material));
```

because I presume OpenGL will have 20 `vec4` followed by 80 `float` in memory.

So how could I do this? Do I have to calculate the offset of every element singularly?

Also, how should I index the material used by a mesh? Should I pass the material index as a vertex attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial suggestion was a struct containing arrays. So why not instead do the opposite: an array containing structs?

```
struct Material
{
    vec4 Color;
    float Specular;
    float Roughness;
    float Metallic;
    float ReflectionIntensity;
}

layout(std140) uniform Materials
{
    Material mtls[20];
};
```

You would then build a similar array on the CPU.

Now to do this, you *must* make sure to follow `std140`'s alignment rules. Particularly important is the alignment of structures and arrays. Since `Material` has a `vec4` in it, its base alignment is 16. And the stride between elements of an array must be multiples of the base alignment of the array element.

Therefore, `mtls[20]` will be 32 * 20 bytes in size. Even if you removed a single float from `Material`, it will still be that size.

If you really wanted to keep the struct-of-array approach, you would simply need to use a corresponding data structure on the CPU.

Comment: Well, I don't really need to stick to a struct-of-array approach, I can do like you suggested (it's also simpler to think of). Also, I don't think the alignment will be the problem since I'm querying the uniform block to know the offsets and everything. I will try.

Comment: Going from my approach (struct-of-array) to your approach something changed: with my approach the buffer size was 1600 bytes and every element has an offset of 320 bytes from the previous element; with your approach the total buffer size is now 640 bytes, and every element of the struct has an offset of `[0, 16, 20, 24, 28]` bytes. Is it right? With your method I am able to have a bigger buffer also!

Comment: @zeb: "*with my approach the buffer size was 1600 bytes*" No, it was not. `(16+4+4+4+4) * 20 == (16*20 + 4*20 + 4*20 + 4*20 + 4*20)`. The math works out the same either way. "*I'm querying the uniform block to know the offsets and everything.*" Why? The *whole point* of `std140` layout is that you don't *have* to query the offsets and alignments. You know them a priori from the structure definition.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. I just wanted to be sure. By the way, "_the buffer size was 1600_", I got that value by using `glGetActiveUniformBlockiv` with `GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE`

Comment: @zeb: I forgot about rule #4: the stride of arrays is always rounded up to the alignment of a `vec4`. So every `float` array element in your struct-of-arrays takes up the same size as a `vec4`. That's where the disparity comes from: 5 * (16*20) = 1600.

Comment: it seems it worked out the way you suggested, I still have to make some changes though. One question: using the `std140` layout, the offset of each element of the buffer will be the same? So, if I have a `vec4` or an array of floats the offset will be 16 bytes, if I have at least a `mat4` the offset of each element will be 64 bytes?

Comment: @zeb: The OpenGL specification section on std140 is not that complex to read (7.6.2.2). Also, you seem to be confusing terms. offset is the number of bytes from the beginning to that value. You seem to be talking about *alignment*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112924/discussion-between-zeb-and-nicol-bolas).

Comment: everything work, thank you very mush for your help. Reading better the OpenGL specifications about layout `std140` I was able to fill the buffers correctly and the first step of my batched renderer works like a charm.